# Having Isotope resize images to best fit fixed-sized container?

Tags: layout, jquery-plugins, jquery-isotope

I'm wondering how/if I can use Isotope to fill a given space.

I've got several images, 6-12 which I pull from a DB query (i don't know the exact size ahead of time), and I want to make them fit on a page so as to maximize all possible space. The page's size is fixed and doesn't change (It's A4 or ~8 1/2 x 11), images have approximately the same size but different only on orientation. Is Isotope capable of finding some clever way to resize and arrange items, so that they take up the most space within the container? Including both height and width of the box.

Answer (score 0):

There's an excellent plugging that does just that. Check it out.

http://johnpolacek.github.io/imagefill.js/packery.html